# Creating Models from MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

Is there any way to create models from MongoDB Database like Loopback has model discovery to reverse engineer database schemas into model definitions.

Comment: There are third party tools for reverse-engineering schema from MongoDB data sources, but questions asking to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You might want to try posting on the [Software Recommendations StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) instead.

Comment: If you are asking about Loopback in particular: "The LoopBack MongoDB connector does not support discovery. However, you can use *instance instrospection*, which creates a LoopBack model from an existing JavaScript object." (source: [`loopback-example-database`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-database#8-add-a-script-to-perform-instance-instrospection-discovery)).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry my question was specific to LoopBack. Yes I am aware, LoopBack discovery module does not support MongoDB. hence I was trying to find someone has some way. Today I am doing it in round about way by converting JSON to schema using some tools and then copy that into a model file.

I will check this example you mentioned.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Because mongoDB database model is flexible it is not possible or not practical to create data model from it. Let me explain it this way. In SQL we create tables and columns manually or programmatically which does not change overtime. On the other hand in mongoDB you do not need to create tables and fields, when you invoke insert function on mongodb the data is stored in document model structure, which can be change over time depending on the data submitted for the next insertion.

Comment: While you are right, I differ. Thought document DBs are designed/intended above way

a. There are many scenarios where the document structure would not change or not change often.

b. One has to write server apps and front ends by fixing certain schema for the MongoDB Document.

Some developers take approach of fixing schema some dont. This depends case to case.

Loopback and quite few other frameworks like Mongoose ask to create schema  and then use the MongoDB.

Comment: To fix schema have you tried mongoosejs? But you have to create data model manually.